erorr in npm install give me this ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-LMIgiIrhigmPrs03JHpxUh2yISK3vLFPkAodPeo0+BuF7wA2FoQbkEg1u8gBYBThncu7e1odfIXVuTqLRUjw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-LMIgiIrhigmPrs03JHpxUh2yISK3vLFPkAodPeo0+BuF7wA2FoQbkEg1u8gBYBThncu7e1odfIXVuTqLRUjw== but got sha512-LMIgiIrhigmPrs03JHpxUh2yISK3vLFPkAodPeo0+BuF7wA2FoQbkEg1u8gBYBThncu7e1oEDUfIXVuTqLRUjw==. (19063 bytes)

How should I solve this error?
I tried to download a React app from GitHub. When I run npm i and npm start, it works fine.
However, when I download my own repository and run npm i, it doesn't work and gives me an error.

I'd try removing or renaming package-lock.json - I'd guess that's where it stores the hashes.

Does this answer your question? When I run `npm install`, it returns with `ERR! code EINTEGRITY` (npm 5.3.0)

It usually happens if the downloaded package's checksum does not match with the  expected checksum defined in package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json file.
Try the following:

Delete the node modules dir rm -rf node_modules
Delete the package.lock.json file rm package-lock.json
npm install

